# doubly-linked list

Tags: java, collections

Hi
I want to know that how can I copy my objects from an arrayList to a doubly linked list?
also my DNode constructor is :

```
    public DNode(Object element, DNode prev, DNode next) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}
```

i.e. when I write such a code my program doesn't work  :

```
  DNode node = new DNode(pointList.get(0),null, null);

        for (int i = 1; i < pointList.size(); i++) {
        DNode dNode = new DNode(pointList.get(i), node, null);
        dList.addLast(dNode);
        }
```

also i have written doubly linked list which has addAfter and addBefore methods and also much more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`java.util.LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a doubly-linked list.

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list.

You can create it by passing the array list as constructor argument:

```
List linkedList = new LinkedList(arrayList);
```

**Update:** The `java.util.LinkedList` has `add(index, element)` which, combined with `indexOf(..)` should cover the `addBefore` and `addAfter` methods. You can extend `LinkedList` to add these convenient methods if you like.

Comment: I have created my doubly linked list that has methods like addAfter and addBefore and more but when I add my objects to the list my program doesn't work well.

Comment: nice ,I didn't know it before :)

Comment: would you please suggest me some tutorial for learning much more about this point?

Comment: the javadoc of `LinkedList` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the element at the end of the linked list has a 'next' property of 0:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
int next = currentElement.next;
while(next != 0) {
    arrayList.add(currentElement);
    next = currentElement.next;
}
```

You can also use `java.util.LinkedList` as that is an in-built representation of a doubly-linked list. Using this type means you can pass the linked list into the constructor of an ArrayList